# Using jquery.dataTables.js 1.10.11, the table doesn't initially show additions to tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using "jquery.dataTables.js" 1.10.11.(https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js) The problem is when I add another value, User Name in this case, on my tables the number on the bottom showing number of User Names does not change to show the addition. I have to reload the page in order to see the new number. I need it to automatically load the new number right when the new value is added to the table, not after it reloads. Has anyone used this datatable, and have a solution to this problem?
[image: Number does not change with addition to the table]

Answer (score 1):

Using t.row.add increments the counter as shown on https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html.

```
oTable.row.add( [
        'Lock',
        'Password',
        'Comment',
        'Groups',
        'Roles'
    ] ).draw();
```

if your table is serverside based you should use

```
oTable.fnDraw();
```